# React Tutorial - Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I need to learn React in the next day and started with the official tutorial. All is good until I get to this state of my code where I am getting an error and am not sure how to get around it:

```
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
     <!-- script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script -->
     <script type="text/babel">
       var CommentBox = React.createClass( {
          render: function() {
            return (
              <div className = "commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList />
                <CommentForm />
                <Comment />
              </div>
              );
         }
       });

          var CommentList = React.createClass({
            render: function () {
              return (
               <div className = "commentList">
                  <Comment author = "Michael Johnson">This is one 
                      comment</Comment>
                  <Comment author = "Daniel Kammer">This is the 'second' 
                      comment</Comment>
                  </div>
               );
            }
          });

           var CommentForm = React.createClass({
            render: function () {
              return (
                <div className = "commentForm">
                   Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
                </div>
                );
            }
          });

          var Comment = React.createClass({
           var md = new Remarkable();
           render: function () {
          return (
            <div className = "comment">
              <h2 className = "commentAuthor">
                {this.props.author}
              </h2>
            *** ERROR IS GENERATED BY THE BELOW STATEMENT ***
                {md.render(this.props.children.toString())}
            </div>
            );
        }
      });
```

The rest of the tutorial continues forward with the md.render statement - so I need to understand how to resolve this error

Comment: what is the output of "this.props.children" in console? And what is Remarkable()? Provide more information & link to the tutorial please.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by `<Comment />` in `ComentBox` component, probably. Children components are required for proper work of `Comment` component, but closed tag  has no childrens (`this.prop.childrens` are null or undefined => method `toString` is not declared)